# How should I define ranges in ingress security group using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, port

I cannot find how I should define ranges using Terraform in ingress security groups. Checking the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group#to_port) fields `to_port` and `from_port` suport range port. However, I do not find how to configure it.

working example using aws CLI:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --region $REGION \
    --group-name test \
    --protocol tcp \
    --port 50000-50001 \
    --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
```

But I do not manage to do the same using terraform. I have tried configuring the same in the security group resource:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name        = "allow_tls"
  description = "Allow TLS inbound traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    description      = "allow_tls"
    from_port        = 50000-50001
    to_port          = 50000-50001
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "allow_tls"
  }
}
```

And the problem that I have is that it is automatically setting `to_port` and `from_port` to `-1` value.

```
# from terraform plan output
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = "allow_tls"
              + from_port        = -1
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = -1
            }
```

also tried using `aws_security_group_rule` and it have the same behavior. Any idea how it can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
    from_port        = 50000
    to_port          = 50001
```